# Is there a proof of the multichoose identity.

Tags: combinatorics

The number of ways to select unordered subsets of size k with replacement from a set of size n is ${n+k-1\choose k}$. Is there a proof of this identity?

Comment: The Wikipedia article on Stars and Bars (combinatorics) is quite good.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that the only thing that matters in picking/defining these subsets is the multiplicity of each element chosen. The subsets must be of size $k$ so the individual multiplicities of each element must sum to $k$. Thus, we can represent a chosen subset by tuples $(m_1,m_2,\cdots,m_n)$ where $m_i$ is the number of times $i$ is chosen, and $\sum_{i=1}^nm_i=k$, with $0\leq m_i\leq k$.

This problem is considerably easier, since we can represent the tuples as:

$$(3,2,0,1,4,0)=(\cdot\cdot\cdot|\cdot\cdot||\cdot|\cdot\cdot\cdot\cdot||),$$

which shows a bijection between these tuples and the number of ways we can wedge vertical bars between or around $n$ points. Equivalently this is equal to the number of ways we can pick $n-1$ slots for the dots out of $n+k-1$ bins (note that a dot can never be in the last bin). Or, we can instead pick $k$ slots for the bars out of $n+k-1$. This is of course $\binom{n+k-1}{n-1}=\binom{n+k-1}{k
}$.